# Pdf not opening from Internet Explorer download Dialog box

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

When clicked the hyperlink for pdf , the dialog comes with open, save and cancel. But when clicked on Open, the pdf does not open.This issue is only on Internet Explorer. All other browsers supports well. I am using Asp.Net c# . Please advice

**pdf opens in internet explorer if the name of the pdf is smaller. If name is large, open button click does not work in internet explorer 9.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

1) Go to Tool -> Internet Option -> Advanced

2) Scroll to the bottom.

3) Find check box for "Do not save encrypted pages to disk" and uncheck it.

**OR**

I found 1 solution [here](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-484572-internet-explorer-stops-working-with-pdf-file) . It says-

A. Close your web browser.

B. Start Acrobat or Adobe Reader.

C. Choose Edit > Preferences.

D. Select Internet in the list on the left.

E. Uncheck "Display PDF in Browser", and click OK.

F. Restart Internet explorer.

Answer (score 2):

```
1.Check your browser version first.

2.Check whether you have installed all the updates.

3.I have found this link which will be helpful for you.
```

[Url to troubleshoot openig pdf in IE](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/cant-view-pdf-web.html)